# manually launch Captive Network Assistant?

Tags: launcher, capnet-assist

Where I work, the internet requires a sign-in. *Usually,* the [Captive Network Assistant](https://github.com/elementary/capnet-assist/) pops up at the right time, and allows me to log in.

But sometimes when the connection is broken, or I've closed/locked my laptop, I get a notification that I need to sign in to the network again, and the assistant is nowhere to be seen. Nothing comes up when searching in the launcher. The only way that I've been able  to launch the program in that situation is searching for it in AppCenter and then clicking **Open**.

I'd like to be able to launch it from the terminal, or set a keyboard shortcut to launch it, but it doesn't work. Do I need to add something to my $PATH?

```
$ io.elementary.capnet-assist -f 

  zsh: command not found: io.elementary.capnet-assist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capnet-assist is a flatpak app now and you'll need to run it like this:

`flatpak run io.elementary.capnet-assist`

TIP: you can use `flatpak list` to see all the flatpak apps installed.